# Use a bluetooth headset for media audio on a Nexus 7 running Android 4.2

Tags: nexus-7, 4.2-jelly-bean, bluetooth-audio

I have a Jawbone Bluetooth headset paired to my new Nexus 7 tablet. In the paired Bluetooth devices section, it show that it is paired under the `Phone Audio` profile. I just want all the audio to go through the Jawbone earpiece, when it is connected. So far even though it is connected **I can't get any sound out of the ear piece** and the tablet still uses it's built in microphone.

**So is there a way to change the Jawbone's Bluetooth profile from `Phone Audio` to all, or media, etc?** I don't know how to change this, and I'm not even sure what the `Phone Audio` profile is for, since I'm new to Android and this isn't really a phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an app called [Mono for Bluetooth](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxistar.monobluetoothfree&hl=en) that allows you route the devices sound via mono bluetooth headset. I'm sure there are other apps, but this is the first one I found and it seems to work fine. It also does the following:

- sound indication when routing is switched on
- restores sound volume after switching off the routing
- indication when routing is on in status bar
- restores bluetooth routing after phone call

Supports Android 2.2 and higher.